# DEX error when using YoutubeAndroidPlayer api in my android app

Tags: android, video, youtube-api

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID
>   not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

[image: enter image description]

When i use YoutubeAndroidPlayer.jar in my lib folder and check it in properties -> java build path -> order and export.

Please give me solution....

Answer (score 0):

[you app Over 64K Methods.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

you can use proguard
in your app level 
[image]
or open multiDex
[image]
and add  com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1 dependencies

Comment: Sorry, but i'm using Eclipse.